# LINQ expression: How to get the most recent results?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that keeps a history of everything that happened to our company client list.  This is what it looks like:

```
Company CompanyType Change_Dt   Chng_Type
Apple   Large      12/12/2012   A
Dell    Large      12/01/2012   A
Adobe   Mid        06/12/2012   A
Dell    Large      11/01/2012   D
eBay    Small      11/02/2012   A
Apple   Large      10/29/2012   D
Dell    Large      10/20/2012   A
eBay    Small      10/02/2012   D
3M      Small      09/02/2012   D
Adobe   Mid        05/30/2012   D
```

The problem is that there are many CompanyTypes and I just want to keep a list with the latest "A"ctive companies.  In the end the I should have 1 list that looks like:

```
CompanyType Company Change_Dt   Chng_Type
Large   Apple      12/12/2012   A
Large   Dell       12/01/2012   A
Mid     Adobe      06/12/2012   A
Small   eBay       11/02/2012   A
```

The query that I have so far is:

```
table.OrderBy(t => CompanyType).Where(t => Chng_Type.Equals("A"))
```

How do I complete the query?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about that query doesn't already satisfy what you have in your example? Did you also want to sort by change date?

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = table.Where(t => t.Chng_Type.Equals("A"))
                 .GroupBy(t => t.Company)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Change_Dt)
                               .FirstOrDefault());
```

Explanation:

- filter entries by company type
- group filtered entries by company name (i.e. all entries of Apple will be in one group)
- from each group select entry with latest date

Comment: Should it begin with `var query = table.Where(t => t.Chng_Type.Equals("A"))` ?

Comment: @JefferyKhan thanks! Just copy-pasted that filtering condition from question